# Dynamic operators in javascript

Tags: variables, math, switch-statement, operators

I currently have a large switch statement:

```
switch (arg) {
    case '+':
        equals = num1 + num2;
        break;
    case '-':
        equals = num1 - num2;
        break;
    case '*':
        equals = num1 * num2;
        break;
    case '/':
        equals = num1 / num2;
        break;
    case '%':
        equals = num1 % num2;
        break;
    default:
        error();
        return;
}
```

I wanted to know if there was anyway that I could do something like

```
equals = num1 /** Do the operation defined by a variable */ num2
```

Or something like that so I dont have the large switch statement I wasn't even sure where to start looking for something like this since things like "Dynamic operators in js" doesnt bring up what im looking for, any help is apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using object with methods.

```js
const operations = {
  "+": (a, b) => a + b,
  "-": (a, b) => a - b,
  "*": (a, b) => a * b,
  "/": (a, b) => a / b,
  "%": (a, b) => a % b,
};

const action = (op, a, b) => operations[op](a, b);

console.log(action("+", 5, 6));
console.log(action("/", 4, 2));
```

Creating function dynamically. Refer [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) for details and security concerns.

Alternavely, you can create function dynamically.

```js
function createOperation(op) {
    return new Function('return arguments[0]' + op + 'arguments[1]'); 
}

const add = createOperation('+');
const sub = createOperation('-');

console.log(add(5, 6))
console.log(sub(5, 2))
```